# Deserialize elasticsearch response in object

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, deserialization

I am getting below response from ElasticSearch REST API.

```
{
    hits:
    {
        hits:[{
            _source: { type:"test" }
        }]
    }
}
```

I am trying to deserialize the same using...

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(response)
```

Following is the Document class structure, however it is failing to populate values in object. Values in deserialized object always remains null.

```
class Document
{
    public Hits hits { set; get; }
}

class Hits
{
    public IEnumerable<Source> _source { set; get; }
}

class Source
{
    public string type { set; get; }
}
```

How to deserialize the given response? or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
class Document
{
    public Hits hits { set; get; }
}

class Hits
{
    public IEnumerable<Hit> hits { set; get; }
}

class Hit
{
    public Source _source { set; get; }
}

class Source
{
    public string type { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that should do the job. You were missing class Hit. Hits is actually an array of objects, having source property, being class Hit. There is a great way to generate classes you need using Visual Studio. Copy your json example, navigate to studio, open an empty cs file (this is important, otherwise it want work) and go to 'Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes'. This will generate you all classes you need, with all needed structure.